# Defining and using the variable to schedule the workflow in collibra

Tags: workflow, collibra

Currently the timer event have this Cron job configuration embedded in the workflow code-

```
<timerEventDefinition>
        <timeCycle>0 58 16 1/1 * ? *</timeCycle>
</timerEventDefinition>
```

I  want this as a configurable property on workflow overview page. 
I was trying to workaround the expression property in the timer main config but no luck on that.
Any idea on how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to define a start form variable in your workflow with readable false? And then in your Time cycle property you can use an expression like ${} You can then manage the cron expression in the workflow definition in the DGC.

```
  **Start Form Variable Example:**
  Id = cronExpressionVariable
  type = string
  Default = 0 58 16 1/1 * ? *
  Required = false
  Readable = false
  Writeable = true

  Then in the timer, set the Time Cycle = ${cronExpressionVariable}
```

You can then maintain the value in the workflow definition without having to update the workflow itself.